# app engine network error - what to do?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, networking, google-cloud-endpoints

A fairly straightforward question.
Suppose an Android client calls an java enpoint on a Google App Engine to update a bank account. It executes, but during sending the response back, a network error happens. But the client never knows that:

- the network error happened before the bank account update took place on App Engine, in which case everything is fine and he can retry.
- the network error happened AFTER the execution on App Engine, in which case it will be wrong to retry and update the bank account once more!!

So, question:  in case a network error happens, there is an obvious choice for the client to retry or not retry. How can he determine the correct course of action? I.e. somehow find out that the network error occurred before the actual activity on the back end and hence retry, OR  realize that it was a network error on the way back and correctly not retry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjust the transaction protocol such that the client connects again to the server to get the transaction status.

This offers a lot of flexibility, for example your client can:

- reliably detect if the GAE app has actually received the transaction request or not
- not block during the transaction execution (important in case there's a problem between the GAE app and the banking system or if the transaction takes a lot of time)
- track transaction failures and retry if needed
- cancel a still pending transaction

Comment: Interesting suggestion, thanks. I also thought about something like this, but thought it was more complicated than it could be. But now I am reconsidering this. But in general - this seems like a fairly standard situation in networked software. Isn't there a standard logical solution in place already? (Or maybe what you suggested is it?) I wasn't able to search one out anywhere.

Comment: seems also the user would first look at a log and see their balance to determine if it happened. you can also attempt detecting duplicate requests and show a warning (same amount and date off by less than 5 minutes for example, which can be kept in memcached)

Comment: I guess it really depends on the system's architecture, requirements and implementation approaches. IMHO customizing a one-size-fits-all generic infrastructure to work for a specific application can easily be more work than implementing an app-specific solution :) (And building such generic infra may be too much trouble)

Comment: @ZigMandel: auto-detecting duplicates is not trivial: for example what if the comm outage lasts more than 5 min? But addressable with a unique per-client transaction ID. Still, how many retries, when to stop, unnecessary client/app ops, etc...

Comment: @DanCornilescu agree your idea with unique id is more complete.

Comment: @DanCornilescu - why do an extra step and perform that "check if transaction succeeded call"? When all you can do is once you get a network error you just resubmit the same transaction with the same identifier. If transaction already succeeded during the prior call, the backend should just throw a "transaction with this id already took place" and that's it. So, just include a transaction id every time during backend call.

Comment: Sure, if you feel comfy with it. I prefer the flexibility mentioned in the answer.